# How can I make it insert one by one while loading two data at the same time?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers, insert

```
INSERT INTO tbl_product_attribute_value (db_id,db_product_id,db_category_id,db_attribute_id,db_attribute_value_id, db_value)
VALUES
     (1999,217,2264,47,null , 'a'),
     (2000,217,2264,47,null , 'b')
limit 1;
RETURNING * ;
```

I want to add a limit to this query after insert trigger. Because I have this error because of the query

> SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> Where: SQL statement "SELECT (select db_value from  tbl_product_attribute_value where (db_attribute_id = 47 and db_attribute_value_id is null) )"
> PL/pgSQL function deneme2() line 7 at assignment

And I have a trigger for the insert function

```
 create or replace function deneme2() 
 returns trigger 
 as $$
 declare 
 idd integer;
 name varchar;
 begin 
    idd := (SELECT MAX(db_id)+1 FROM public.tbl_attribute_value);
 name := (select db_value from  tbl_product_attribute_value where (db_attribute_id = 47 and db_attribute_value_id is null) );
 insert into tbl_attribute_value (db_id, db_name) values (idd,name);
    update tbl_product_attribute_value  SET db_attribute_value_id = idd  where (db_attribute_id = 47 and db_attribute_value_id is null);
    return new;
 end;
 $$
 language plpgsql;
```

```
 create trigger assign_id_attribute_value
 after INSERT
 on tbl_product_attribute_value
 for each row 
 execute procedure deneme2();
```

Comment: `SELECT MAX(db_id)+1 ?` is a horrible way to generate unique IDs - it will fail if you run concurrent inserts.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a variable use POSTGRES `INSERT INTO SELECT`

You find it in the examples https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

```
 create or replace function deneme2() 
 returns trigger 
 as $$
 declare 
     idd integer;
 begin 
    idd := (SELECT MAX(db_id)+1 FROM public.tbl_attribute_value);
 
 insert into tbl_attribute_value (db_id, db_name) select idd,db_value from  tbl_product_attribute_value where (db_attribute_id = 47 and db_attribute_value_id is null);
    update tbl_product_attribute_value  SET db_attribute_value_id = idd  where (db_attribute_id = 47 and db_attribute_value_id is null);
    return new;
 end;
 $$
 language plpgsql;
```

Better would be to use a serial auto increment

But with concurrent inserts, you could get problems, that two or more have then the same idd number, so would need to use a transaction, to prveent that

Comment: Don't forget to lock the table public.tbl_attribute_value to avoid concurrency issues with the id's that you generate. It will create concurrency limitations (aka problems), but that's the price you pay for using MAX(). A sequence might be a better idea, but it depends on the goal.

Comment: @FrankHeikens i couldn't find any mention of  `lock the table public.tbl_attribute_value` anywhere maybe a typo?